# How to make the waiting message go away when the perl process is done using Perl CGI

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am working on a project like let users run a perl script from a submit button in a (CGI) HTML page and send the output to another html page, that's how the returned data is displayed to the users. It will take about 2 mins to get the results, so I am wondering to print out a waiting message to users during the running time, message like 'Please wait, processing your request'. When the process is done, users will be directed to the result's html page. My questions is how to print out the waiting time message to users and how to let the waiting message go away when the process is done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=596850

Answer (score -1):

OP's processing time is about 2 minutes.

Perhaps simplest method would be to generate a web page with redirect in 120 seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="120; url=https://www.myserver.com/cgi-bin/result.pl" />
```

[How to redirect to a web page](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-redirect-a-web-page-in-html.html)

Following web page redirects to Microsoft website in 120 second after load

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="120; url=https://www.microsoft.com/" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Wait: processing data</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Other approach would be to utilize [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) / [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp) and send requests to the server 'is it ready yet' and on positive answer show result page.

Comment: Thanks guys. Finally this helped solve my issue:                                                                                 **`print "<META HTTP-EQUIV=refresh CONTENT=\"1;URL=your_url\">\n";`**